# PHP $_GET not working with JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am writing an app using JQuery Mobile and PHP.

The problem:
When I try to pass values from one JQuery mobile page (e.g. from #page1 to #page2 using Ajax and PHP) $_GET does not retrieve the values in the URL.

The url will look like this:

> myApp/#page3?fid=Milk+Cheese+Butter

PHP is unable to get `"?fid="`.

I figure this is a problem with the way the URL is setup using JQuery mobile (single page). Any help resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

My Ajax (snippet):

```
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if((request.readyState==4) && (request.status==200 || request.status == 304)) {
        if(request.responseText!= undefined){
            window.location.replace('#page3?fid='+request.responseText+'');
        }
    }
}
```

First PHP page:

```
<?php 
    include '../connect/connect.php';
    $ingredients = $_POST['ingredients'];
    if (empty ($ingredients) === false){
        foreach($ingredients  as $key => $ingre){
            if ($ingre != 'undefined'){
                $refine = substr($ingre, "4");
                $refined = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $refine);
                echo $refined;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Second PHP page:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['fid'])) {
         echo 'yes';
    } else {
        echo 'no';
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: It appears that you have the get string after a hash sign. PHP doesn't get anything after the hash sign. That is stripped out by the browser and never even sent to the server.

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured. But JQuery mobile requires that the # be there to navigate between pages. ...Is there a way around this?

Comment: Parse hash string in your js and get vars from it

Comment: The hash should be at the back, so the proper url would be `myApp/?fid=Milk+Cheese+Butter#page3`

Comment: Thank you @GolezTrol! You the man. ...I've been trying to make this work for hours.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. Calling the escaping functions manually usually leads to mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash (everything starting from the `#` character) is not sent to the server. The hash should be at the end of the url, after the so called query string, so the proper url would be:

```
myApp/?fid=Milk+Cheese+Butter#page3
```